# Assembly 8086 - Using int21h function 5Ah to create a randomly named file

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, temporary-files

As the title implies, I want to use this function in order to generate a random, unique file name.

My code:

```
.model tiny
.code

ORG 100H

HOST:

MOV AH, 5Ah
XOR CX, CX
MOV DX, OFFSET HI
int 21h;

MOV BX, DX

mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
    
mov ah,9
mov dx, OFFSET BX
int 21h
HI DW '\'

END HOST



END
```

Here is the documentation for the function -> [image]

Thing is, I don't understand what should be put in `DX`. Path to the folder where the file should be created? Shouldn't it be created by default in the current directory? If not, how can I do that? Tried it with '/' as seen above. Documentation says something about a path ending with 'backslash' + 13 bytes to receive generated filename, but I honestly have no idea what that's supposed to mean. What should be added to the code so that the function will work?

Comment: You need to allocate space big enough for your directory and a generated file name of length 13 (presumably 8.3 format for 12 bytes and a terminating zero). If you want it in the current directory, preset the buffer with dot backslash .\ and make sure it has size at least 15.

Comment: Excuse me for insisting, but how exactly would I do that? Is it just a matter of changing HI (buffer variable) to --> HI DW '.\'? Excuse me for the idiocy, I'm an absolute beginner and I cannot fully understand your answer. If you could point me to the modifications that should be done to the code, I'd be grateful.

Comment: HI DB 13 dup (?) for the buffer. But where do I put the .\?

Comment: `HI DB '.\', 13 dup(0)`

Comment: Thank you! Now the function works as intended!

Comment: @Jester: Post your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DOS.CreateUniquelyNamedFile function 5Ah creates a file with a guaranteed unique name in the specified directory. Even though your documentation speaks about *a path ending with 'backslash' + 13 bytes*, DOS creates just an 8 character file name like "BEAAAGDB" (no extension). *'backslash' + 9 bytes* would be enough. Of course, if you want to play it safe then just allocate all 13 bytes.

To create in a particular directory use e.g. `db '\DOS\TEMP\', 9 dup (0)`.
To create in the current directory use `db '.\', 9 dup (0)`.
To create in the parent directory use `db '..\', 9 dup (0)`.
To create in the root directory use `db '\', 9 dup (0)` or `db 10 dup (0)`.

```
.model tiny
.code

ORG 100h

HOST:
      mov dx, offset TFile
      xor cx, cx            ; Attribute NORMAL
      mov ah, 5Ah           ; DOS.CreateUniquelyNamedFile
      int 21h               ; -> AX CF

      ; Because we exit immediately, there's no need to check the CF for failure
      ; nor do we need to 'close' the file (Terminate does that for us)

      mov ax, 4C00h         ; DOS.Terminate
      int 21h

TFile db '.\', 0
    ; db 12 dup(?)     ; implicit at the end of a .COM file

END HOST
```

*TFile* is the very last item in this .COM program.  So in this case there's no need to use more than the one zero byte as the terminator for the implicit-length C string that DOS will read from this buffer.

.COM programs can already use space beyond the end of the file as uninitialized buffer space, so the actual path buffer extends into that.